# Search multidimensional array with Key name and return values as result

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I am PHP beginner so please be patient with me. I spent couple of hours going through many threads already on multidimensional arrays search but none of them fits my situation. Sounds really simple but kind of stuck as I want to search by key name and retrieve values against it.

Tried some methods like array_column but returns an empty array.
I simply want to loop through array finding key name as: "largeImageURL" from all the array elements and want to return its values.

```
{
"total": 4692,
"totalHits": 500,
"hits": [
{
    "id": 195893,
    "pageURL": "https://pixabay.com/en/blossom-bloom-flower-195893/",
    "type": "photo",
    "tags": "blossom, bloom, flower",
    "previewURL": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/15/09/12/flower-195893_150.jpg"
    "previewWidth": 150,
    "previewHeight": 84,
    "webformatURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/35bbf209e13e39d2_640.jpg",
    "webformatWidth": 640,
    "webformatHeight": 360,
    "largeImageURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/ed6a99fd0a76647_1280.jpg",
    "fullHDURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/ed6a9369fd0a76647_1920.jpg",
    "imageURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/ed6a9364a9fd0a76647.jpg",
    "imageWidth": 4000,
    "imageHeight": 2250,
    "imageSize": 4731420,
    "views": 7671,
    "downloads": 6439,
    "favorites": 1,
    "likes": 5,
    "comments": 2,
    "user_id": 48777,
    "user": "Josch13",
    "userImageURL": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/user/2013/11/05/02-10-23-764_250x250.jpg",
},
{
    "id": 73424,
    ...
},
...
]
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried already? And please don't say "some things".

Comment: you are expecting collection of value with matching key right?

Comment: @narayansharma91yes exactly!

Comment: Bar the use of _..._, your json is invalid on several counts

Comment: How did you use array_column. In my mind it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to convert your JSON object to an array and compare like below.

```
$results = json_decode($your_array);
$match_result = [];
foreach($results['hits'] as $result) {
   if (isset($result['largeImageURL']) {
      $match_result [] = $result['largeImageURL'];
   }
}
print_r($match_result);
```

Comment: Ha a check for key if it is there or not. Good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode your JSON response into an array and loop through `hits` array till you find the key and return the data.

```
$returnArr = array();//to store values of largeImageURL
$json = "<json response>";//your json string here
$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);//convert json to an array
//now we will loop through hits
foreach($decoded_json['hits'] as $hit){
    $returnArr[] = $hit['largeImageURL'];
}
print_r($returnArr);
```